# Should I put view strings into yaml file for easier testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization, integration-testing

For integration testing, I check content of pages, to make sure user would see what I want.

For example:

```
it "shows list of articles" do
    get :articles
    response.body.should have_content("Articles found:")
end
```

Somewhere in articles view, there is this line:

```
<h1>Articles found:</h1>
```

I want to get rid of strings duplicity, make the code easier to maintain and tests more solid. I'm considering putting those strings into config/locales/en.yml and then do something like this

```
it "shows list of articles" do
    get :articles
    response.body.should have_content(I18n.t('title'))
end
```

and in the view:

```
<h1><%=t :title %></h1>
```

Does it make sense from long term perspective or is there a better/standardized way?

Comment: this is the Rails way for i18n, so you can use it freely even if you've simply testing purposes

Comment: Also, consider that your approach (the second one) is slightly dangerous: If the test succeeds, you wouldn't know if you forgot to set the I18n for 'title' (depending on your settings, this would possibly result in '').

Comment: @mosch good point! It could be catched by I18n settings, right? Something like "missing translation: title". Then I could be more confident about proper view displayed. Missing translation would be another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't, internationalized strings are meant for humans to read.

As an alternative, see if you can structure the document in a way that makes asserting by selects more deterministic.

```
it "shows list of articles" do
    get :articles
    assert_select "h1.articles-title"
end
```

And in the view.

```
<h1 class="articles-title"><%=t :title %></h1>
```

While I understand that your original test case asserts the presence of a correct title, I would argue that the greatest benefit for a general integration test like this is the presence of *a title*.

Comment: I think this would make my tests more implementation specific. On the other hand there would also be more consistent control of what is displayed, in case that structure changes.

Comment: After some time, looking back at my question, I agree with not using I18n for test purposes. I will stick with structure tests where appropriate/possible. In other cases, testing to actual text would be more beneficial. Even if it only makes me realize I really want to change that string in view.